# Not able to send commands to cmd.exe process

Tags: c#, cmd, process, stdout, stdin

I am trying to send commands to an open cmd.exe process using `StandardInput.WriteLine(str)`, however none of the commands seem to be sent. First I open a process, with a global variable p (`Process p`).

```
p = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        FileName = @"cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/C" //blank arguments
    }
};

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

After, I try to send a command using a simple method, that logs the result in a text box.

```
private void runcmd(string command)
{
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
    var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    TextBox1.Text = output;
}
```

Right now I am testing it with `DIR`, but `var output` shows up as null, which results in no output. Is there a better way to send a command to the open cmd.exe process?

Comment: You have to call `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` *before* `p.WaitForExit()`, otherwise you can get a deadlock. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx). You didn't mention a deadlock, but this might be your problem.

Comment: Tried getting rid of p.WaitForExit(), and the issue still occurred.

Comment: `Cmd /c` starts then terminates CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could never get it to work with synchronous reads of stdout without closing stdin, but it does work with async reading for stdout/stderr. No need to pass in `/c`, you only do that when passing in a command *through* the arguments; you are not doing this though, you are sending the command directly to the input.

```
var p = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = {
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    FileName = @"cmd.exe"}
};
p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args1) => Console.WriteLine(args1.Data);
p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args1) => Console.WriteLine(args1.Data);
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd e:");
p.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Comment: Still nothing. Also I need to keep the process open for multiple commands, so I can't close it.

Comment: @FyreeW With reading the stdout synchronously I could only get it to work by closing stdin no matter what I tried. But everything appears to work fine with async reading for stdout. I edited my answer with the async version.

Comment: I see the cmd shell pop up, but there is no output.

Comment: @FyreeW you have to get rid of `Arguments = "/C"`. If you copy and paste my code exactly it will work, then you gotta work backwards slightly and make it do what you want.

Comment: I made sure to use exactly your code above (just created a new method).

Comment: Are you running a "Console Application"? The `Console.WriteLine()`s write to the application's console, not the spawned "cmd.exe", so if you are running a console app then maybe replace the `Console.WriteLine()`s with your `TextBox1.Text = ` instead.

Comment: I did get it working in a simple console application, however when trying to add it to the textbox, it has an issue with being on a different thread (trying to access the textbox from a different thread than it was created on). Still works though, so this was the solution to the problem! Thanks!