# Multiple process commands fail to get back any response

Tags: c#, r, process

Having a challenge being able to send commands to cmd.exe from via the C# Process class.

Basically I want to call R.exe and then send it several commands to stage the data before I run some R functions and then pull out the result.

But I can't get the result back from a simple 'dir' statemenet :(

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
string pathToR = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin";

p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();

List<string> output = new List<string>();
using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
{
    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("cd " + pathToR);
        sw.WriteLine("dir");


        while (p.StandardOutput.Peek() > -1)
        {
            var peekVal = p.StandardOutput.Peek();
            output.Add(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
foreach (var line in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

p.StandardInput.Close();
p.StandardOutput.Close();
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\users\micah_000\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\RStagingTestApp\RStagingTestApp\bin\Debug>cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

I've seen several variations on this result, but I've never seen any kind of response from my commands :(

Comment: Maybe try with asynchronous reading of stdout. I never figured out why, but the last time I played with sending commands straight to cmd.exe I had to use asynchronous reads as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490894/not-able-to-send-commands-to-cmd-exe-process/38491255#38491255) because the synchronous version specifically did not work. Might be similar issue with R, or any program really.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of places say the async reads work best. I've seen some persuasive, comprehensive explanations for this, but I haven't been able to get it to work for me.

[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/redirecting-standard-inputoutput-using-the-process-class/) one seemed to work. It might have been setting AutoFlush to true. Or just reading once at the end.