# c# abort a external process started by cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

Tags: c#

I have this in a BG worker DoWork()

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();

string fullcmd = "\"" + doorsExe + "\" -osUser -b \"" + "doors_" + genname + ".dxl" + "\"";

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(fullcmd);
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();

string result;

// HERE I WILL BECOME BLOCKED!
if ((result = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()) != string.Empty)
    RaiseMessageEvent(result, Color.Gray);
```

Now I used all this in

```
if (!bgwImport.CancellationPending)
{
...
}
```

But of course, cannot CANCEL since there is a external process that blocks all stuff. It's ok, since UI is not blocked (that's why I used BGW) but I implemented a "Cancel" button that isn't working.

How can I stop

```
cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Switching to async reading of stderr/stdout may fix your deadlock issue. I've done simple version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38491255/5095502) that worked for me. For it to work like your code just change `(sender, args1) => Console.WriteLine(args1.Data);` to append the data to some  string, then at the end that string will be the same as you were expecting your `result` to be.

Comment: Also note you've somewhat given us an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), my comment above is to fix your 'actual' problem of a deadlock, an answer to your stated question is to attach a Process object to `doorsExe` and [`Kill()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx) it.

Comment: Consider fixing the bugs in the code before reaching for the sledgehammer solution.  This program is *very* likely to deadlock when you demand the process to exit first before you start reading its output.

Comment: Guys, please.. the doors.exe it's a horrible mess made by IBM. I just try to capture some info, actually will start hidden threads that writes files, etc. Just impossible (at least not easily) to interact with. When I close (force) my app during process started, it just closes without any complains. So I try to figure out how to cancel the same as .NET does very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty clear with sync/async, thanks for hints. However, I am already in a background worker so async isn't important for the moment.

Finally solved somehow, in case anyone pulls hair out from head like me.

Thanks for -1 anyhow, very encouraging!

Will abort in any condition, I checked in TaskManager, Doors works just fine. However, I spend one hour to figure out how to capture redirected output with no success. Always returned NULL. I just gave up, I only need to cancel that process.

```
            String command = "\"" + doorsExe + "\" -osUser -b doors_" + genname + ".dxl";
            ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c" + command);

            cmdsi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdsi.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);

            while (!cmd.HasExited)
            {

                if (bgwImport.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }

            }
```